# Habrá una manera de hacer la función del color seleccionado un botón que cambie a rojo en php y no depender de javascript y para guardarlo en la BD

Tags: javascript, html

Que tal camaradas programadores, estoy con un proyecto de sistema web de estacionamiento de vehículos, anteriormente ya lo he terminado este proyecto pero en aplicación para escritorio hecho en java ahora quiero pasarlo a un aplicación web.

Bueno la cuestión es que he tenido algunos detalles al momento de ir creando la aplicación, tengo un modal creado con 20 botones simulando los cajones, en javascript tengo la función de cada botón al darle clic cambia a color rojo como ocupado y al darle otra vez clic cambia a verde como disponible, hasta ahí todo funciona bien.

Tengo una base de datos con mysql con una tabla llamada Nivel1 con dos columnas  idCajon y disponible, en cual quiero guardar o actualizar los colores en la base de datos, de esta manera guardar el estatus seleccionado en cada botón.

Mi modal

```
    <div id="modal">
    <div  class="modal">
        <div class="contenedor-cajones">
            <header>Nivel 1</header>
            <label class="close" id="close">X</label>
            <div class="contenedor-cajon">
                <tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon1">Cajón 1</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon2">Cajón 2</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon3">Cajón 3</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon4">Cajón 4</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon5">Cajón 5</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon6">Cajón 6</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon7">Cajón 7</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon8">Cajón 8</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon9">Cajón 9</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon10">Cajón 10</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon11">Cajón 11</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon12">Cajón 12</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon13">Cajón 13</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon14">Cajón 14</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon15">Cajón 15</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon16">Cajón 16</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon17">Cajón 17</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon18">Cajón 18</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon19">Cajón 19</button></tr>
                <tr><button id="cajon20">Cajón 20</button></tr>
                </tr>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Función para cambiar los colores en los botones:

```
    (function () {
        let btncajon1 = document.getElementById("cajon1");
        btncajon1.addEventListener("click", c1);
        let btncajon2 = document.getElementById("cajon2");
        btncajon2.addEventListener("click", c2);
        let btncajon3 = document.getElementById("cajon3");
        btncajon3.addEventListener("click", c3);
        let btncajon4 = document.getElementById("cajon4");
        btncajon4.addEventListener("click", c4);
        let btncajon5 = document.getElementById("cajon5");
        btncajon5.addEventListener("click", c5);
        let btncajon6 = document.getElementById("cajon6");
        btncajon6.addEventListener("click", c6);
       let btncajon7 = document.getElementById("cajon7");
       btncajon7.addEventListener("click", c7);
       let btncajon8 = document.getElementById("cajon8");
       btncajon8.addEventListener("click", c8);
       let btncajon9 = document.getElementById("cajon9");
       btncajon9.addEventListener("click", c9);
       let btncajon10 = document.getElementById("cajon10");
       btncajon10.addEventListener("click", c10);
       let btncajon11 = document.getElementById("cajon11");
       btncajon11.addEventListener("click", c11);
       let btncajon12 = document.getElementById("cajon12");
       btncajon12.addEventListener("click", c12);
       let btncajon13 = document.getElementById("cajon13");
       btncajon13.addEventListener("click", c13);
       let btncajon14 = document.getElementById("cajon14");
       btncajon14.addEventListener("click", c14);
       let btncajon15 = document.getElementById("cajon15");
       btncajon15.addEventListener("click", c15);
      let btncajon16 = document.getElementById("cajon16");
      btncajon16.addEventListener("click", c16);
      let btncajon17 = document.getElementById("cajon17");
      btncajon17.addEventListener("click", c17);
      let btncajon18 = document.getElementById("cajon18");
      btncajon18.addEventListener("click", c18);
     let btncajon19 = document.getElementById("cajon19");
     btncajon19.addEventListener("click", c19);
     let btncajon20 = document.getElementById("cajon20");
     btncajon20.addEventListener("click", c20);

    let contador = 0;

      function c1() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon1.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon1.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
     }

      function c2() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon2.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon2.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
      function c3() {
       if (contador % 2 == 0) {
       btncajon3.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon3.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c4() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon4.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon4.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
     }
     function c5() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon5.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon5.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
     }
     function c6() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon6.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon6.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c7() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon7.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon7.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
     contador += 1;
      }
     function c8() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon8.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon8.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c9() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon9.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon9.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c10() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon10.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon10.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c11() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon11.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon11.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }

     function c12() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon12.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon12.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c13() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon13.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon13.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c14() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon14.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon14.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }

     function c15() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon15.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon15.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c16() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon16.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon16.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c17() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon17.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon17.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c18() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon18.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon18.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c19() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon19.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon19.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
      }
     function c20() {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {
      btncajon20.style.backgroundColor = "#E60000";
      } else {
      btncajon20.style.backgroundColor = "#0DCA0D";
      }
      contador += 1;
     }
  })();
```

Visualizar https://codepen.io/angel82/pen/qBqNoaX

Comment: Y bien, cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Habrá una manera de hacer esa función del  color seleccionado de un botón en php y no depender de javascript y para guardarlo en la BD

Comment: La pregunta va en la pregunta, no en un comentario. Recuerda que puedes editarla :P  SObre tu pregunta, con sólo PHP tendrías que refrescar la página cada vez que cambies el color seleccionado enviando un form, procesar el parámetro que entregues en la petición y guardar eso cada vez. Con JS podrías usar una petición ajax. Y esa generación de elementos html la podrías simplificar un poco con PHP :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Importante:** Esta respuesta no está orientada a solucionar el problema solo con PHP porque no es lo más conveniente y te quedará claro después de leer los dos primeros puntos de la siguiente lista. En cambio, el enfoque es simplificar HTML y Javascript para acercarte a una solución más apropiada.

Tienes varios problemas y creo que lo mejor es ponerlos en orden de importancia:

1. Como bien te sugirió @Alfabravo, lo ideal es ejecutar peticiones AJAX para actualizar los valores en base de datos, de lo contrario, en cada clic se debe recargar la página para mostrar los cambios
2. Casi tengo la certeza de que deberás seguir dependiendo de Javascript de una u otra forma; a menos que hagas un formulario para actualizar cada cajón, con la consecuente recarga de página
3. Tienes un contador general que intentas usar para todos los botones y no funciona como esperas. Por ejemplo, haz clic en "Cajón 1" y se cambia, luego haz clic en otro, supongamos "Cajón 6", este no se cambia porque el contador se modificó para reflejar un estado "ocupado" para otro botón y debes hacer otro clic para que realmente funcione
4. Tienes un HTML mal formado, porque las etiquetas `<tr>` solo deben usarse dentro de tablas y no pueden ser contenedor de otras `<tr>`. Desconozco cómo es que se muestra "correctamente"

Dejando de lado el HTML, te sugiero no asignar ID a los botones, es mejor una clase que te permita obtenerlos todos con una sola instrucción y recorrerlos para asignar a todos la misma función a ejecutar cuando reciban clic.

Dentro de esta función, en lugar de cambiar el estilo, agregas o eliminas la clase `ocupado`, el método `.classList.toggle()` lo hace muy fácil. Después obtienes el número, tomado del texto del botón y, al final, determinas si está libre u ocupado, dependiendo de si tiene o no la clase.

Finalmente, ya con los datos necesarios (número de cajón y estado), puedes ejecutar una petición AJAX para actualizar la base de datos. Lectura recomendada: [Uso de fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```js
function actualizaCajon(e) {
    // e es el evento, e.target, el botón que recibió clic
    let boton = e.target;
    // Intercambiar clase "ocupado"
    boton.classList.toggle('ocupado');
    // Saber si está ocupado o disponible
    let ocupado = boton.classList.contains('ocupado');
    // Obtener número de cajón
    let cajon = boton.textContent.replace('Cajón ', '');
    console.log(cajon, ocupado);
    // Ya tienes los datos necesarios
    // Aquí deberías ejecutar una petición AJAX para actualizar la base de datos
}
// Ejecutar cuando cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Obtener todos los botones
    let cajones = document.querySelectorAll('.cajon');
    // Recorrer botones
    cajones.forEach(cajon => {
        // Asignar evento a cada botón
        cajon.addEventListener('click', actualizaCajon);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
}


#modal.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  
}

.contenedor-cajones {
  width: 400px;
  height: 380px;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(180, 219, 217);
}

.contenedor-cajones header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(4, 66, 95);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.contenedor-cajones label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lbl-modal {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn-modal {
  display: none;
}

.contenedor-cajon {
  background: darkgray;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  max-width: 310px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
button {
  background: rgb(13, 202, 13);
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.ocupado {
  background: #E60000;
}
```

```html
    <div id="modal">
    <div  class="modal">
        <div class="contenedor-cajones">
            <header>Nivel 1</header>
            <label class="close" id="close">X</label>
            <div class="contenedor-cajon">
            
                <tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 1</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 2</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 3</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 4</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 5</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 6</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 7</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 8</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 9</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 10</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 11</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 12</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 13</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 14</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 15</button></tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 16</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 17</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 18</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 19</button></tr>
                <tr><button class="cajon">Cajón 20</button></tr>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por su orientación amigo Triby mañana lo checo y comento como resulto.

Comment: Gracias me fue útil tu orientación, ahora voy leer lo que me comentas para actualizar la base de datos.